# How to chain methods and return them inside a method? OOP-PHP

Tags: php, oop

I need to reconstruct head scripts and links so I would like to create a class that I can use for future references.

I started like :

```
class HeadClas{


    public static $headprint;


    function __construct(){

        $this->headprint = "";

    }

    function addLinks(){
        $this->headprint .= "addLinks";
        return $this;
    }

    function addMeta(){
        $this->headprint .= "addMeta";
        return $this;
    }


    function printHead(){
        return $this->headprint;
    }
}
```

In the above case I would need to do

```
$print = new HeadClas;

$print->addLinks()->addMeta();
```

and I would like to do

```
$print = new HeadClas;
$print->printHead();
```

I did try

```
function printHead(){
    return  $this->addMeta()->addLinks();
}
```

But than I need to do

```
$print->printHead()->headprint;
```

What am I missing here?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make the class field non static so it will not mess things up when you use multiple instances.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you expecting `$print->printHead()` to do? The name suggests that it's supposed to print somthing, but all it does is return the property. Are you missing an `echo` somewhere?

Comment: I tested your code and it works what's the problem? just `print $print->printHead();`

Comment: @Barmar I expect it to print addMetaAddlinks , but the way it is coded now to get that output I must do  $print->printHead()->headprint;  and I want to do $print->printHead();

Comment: you are chaining methods so it is normal you have to do $print->printHead()->headprint;

Comment: Why do you expect it to print anything when you don't use `echo` or `print`?

Comment: @Bamar Seriously , can a man ask a question without smarty comments? If you see what I am doing wrong than simply answer. That is why I asked a question.  And it does print what I need , test it yourself , I just want to use different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should make the `$headprint` field non static. Making it static makes it the same reference for all future instances which will create undesirable results.

The `printHead()` should *print* the contents of that field like the method name suggests.

```
class HeadClass {
    public $headprint;

    function __construct() {
        $this->headprint = "";
    }

    function addLinks() {
        $this->headprint .= "addLinks";
        return $this;
    }

    function addMeta() {
        $this->headprint .= "addMeta";
        return $this;
    }


    function printHead() {
        $this->addLinks()->addMeta();
        echo $this->headprint;
    }
}

$printer = new HeadClass();
$printer->printHead();
```

Comment: I dont want to do this $printer->addLinks()->addMeta()->printHead();

I want to use $printer->printHead(); as I asked above

Comment: You're welcome. It's probably better to provide a different method for simply printing the head and the one provided now. As it stands now the method is a bit misleading.

Comment: I see what you mean ,  Thank you again!